# Parsing a large amount of data in nodejs and insert many in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, large-data

So the title is pretty straight forward. I have a file approximately 500mb large, all tab separated values. I implemented a parser that iterates through each line and pushes it to array in form of an object. After all the lines have been iterated, i use mongo's insertmany to store all the values. I tested this on a file with 100 lines of data and it works well. But I'm not sure how this will work on a 500mb of data...i read that insertmany kind of does this thing when mongo oversees the insert and pushes 1000 of items per insert, but what about nodejs? Can it handle this many data, pushing also to array just sounds all sorts of wrong. How do i approach this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a stream reader to do this.  Otherwise you'll load the entire file into memory, create an massively huge array of data, all while trying to make mongo deal with tens of thousands of records.  More than likely server will just blow up.  Just stream it.  That way you dissect the file in "chunks", and will only be inserting a few thousand at a time.

Here is a good article on Node.js streams:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Basically, for "each" chunk of data, you createa  new array of items within that chunk, then have mongo fire those into the DB.  Keep doing that over and over until the file is completely read.  This will consume a small memory footprint, and you'll be amazed at how quickly it works.

Here is an UN-TESTED example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const readable = fs.createReadStream('path to file');
readable.on('data', (chunk) => {
  // will be read as "bytes" in the file, and be accessible in a buffer
  console.log(`Received ${chunk.length} bytes of data.`);

  // so you will need to do something to convert it to human readable stuff... possibly just a tostring()?
  const data = chunk.toString();

  // do something from your data.  Tranform it into the json you need
  let jsonChunk = doSomethingTogetYourJsonDataFromData();
  mongo.insertMany(jsonChunk);
});

readable.on('end', () => {
  console.log('End of file');
});
```

The syntax above is NOT exact nor does it even show the correct dependencies, so look at it as pseudocode, but hopefully it's enough to get you pointed in the right direction.